# Google Glass Immersion - OnClick not working inside a separate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-glass, google-gdk

My problem is pretty simple. I am creating a card based on the result of a HTTP query performed inside a separate thread. The card also has an onclick method and is defined inside a runOnUiThread() located inside the separate thread. However, when the device is tapped, the onclick event isn't fired.

Here is my code:

```
private void login() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        // irrelevant code

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(buildError(code));
            }
        }
    }

    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}

private View buildError(String code) {
    CardBuilder card = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.ALERT);

    card.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning_150);
    if (code.equals("1"))
        card.setText("Incorrect credientals");
    else
        card.setText("Unexpected error");

    card.setFootnote("Tap to try again");

    View cView = card.getView();
    cView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Event", "Clicked"); // This is what isn't triggering
        }
    });
    cView.setFocusable(true);
    cView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    return cView;
}
```

Comment: You're creating a `Runnable` but not running it in any way.  At least not that you've shown us.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Yeah, I am running it, edited code above appropriately (forgot to add that part in the excerpt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the snippet of code contains an error (can't be compiled, missing `;` at the Runnable statement), you were on the right track.

The View simply needs to request the focus in order to be clickable right away. Otherwise you'll have to move the focus manually.

```
cView.setFocusable(true);
cView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
cView.requestFocus();
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch)

Comment: Ah I didn't know about the `cView.requestFocus()` part. Thanks a lot!